# How to display input back to the user on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and I am trying to create a script to display user input in a message box. I have created a textbox and validated it with a regular expression (alphabet only).

Now I need to display the user input in the page itself. How can I do this with JavaScript?

I need to display all the user inputs in the page itself. I need to display the two letter word in one container and three letter word in another container.

This is the code I tried.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Allow() {
                if (!user.title.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && user.title.value != "") {
                    user.title.value = "";


                    alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
                }
            }

            var titles = [];
            var titleInput = document.getElementById("title");
            var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

            function insert( ) {
                titles.push(titleInput.value);
                clearAndShow();
            }

            function clearAndShow() {
                // Clear our fields
                titleInput.value = "";

                // Show our output
                messageBox.innerHTML = "";
                messageBox.innerHTML += "Titles: " + titles.join(", ") + "<br/>";

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>form input</p>
        <form name="user"  action="" onsubmit=" "  method="post">

            User<input id="title" type="text" maxlength="4"  onkeyup=" Allow() " >
                <input type="submit" value="Save/Show" onclick=" insert() " />
        </form>
        <div id="display"></div>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a basic client-side validation, start with `document.getElementById('foo')` and HTML formed like `<input id='foo' value='bar' />`.  You can validate and repopulate using `.value`, somthing like this:

```
var foo = document.getElement('foo');
if (foo.value.match('your regex')) {
   foo.value = foo.value.substr(0, 3);
}
```

For server-side saving and validation, unfortunately you can't do this with only Javascript.

Javascript is client-side, which means it's trapped inside your browser.

To send values back to the server, you need something like PHP or Ruby to receive `POST`ed form values and write them to a file.  Javascript can't write to files for security reasons.

To use Ruby or PHP with Javascript, you could do it dynamically with an Ajax request (intermediate skill level) or by submitting a `<form>` element (beginner skill level).

---

**UPDATE**...after you showed some code :)

You need to put the `<script>` tag *after* the body in the HTML is finished.  When you do `document.getElementById("title")`, it stays null because the HTML isn't finished rendering!

Otherwise, you did everything right.  Here's your code, a little cleaner, and working.

```
<html><head></head><body>

<input id="title" type="text" maxlength="4"  onkeyup="Allow()" >
<input type="submit" value="Save/Show" onclick="insert()" />
<div id="display"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var titles  = [];
var titleInput  = document.getElementById("title");
var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");

function Allow(){
    if (!user.title.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && user.title.value !="") {
        user.title.value="";
        alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
    }
}

function insert () {
    titles.push(titleInput.value);
    clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow () {
    titleInput.value = "";
    messageBox.innerHTML = "";
    messageBox.innerHTML += "Titles: " + titles.join(", ") + "<br/>";
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Your code didn't include the part about the "two letter container" and the "three letter container" so the best I can do there is recommend `substr()` again.

---

**LAST UPDATE**

Here's a basic implementation of two and three letter strings, input delimited using commas like `foo,bar,fo,ba`:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<input id="title" type="text" >
<input type="submit" value="Save/Show" onclick="clearAndShow()" />
<div id="display2letter"></div>
<div id="display3letter"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var titleInput  = document.getElementById("title");
var display2letter  = document.getElementById("display2letter");
var display3letter  = document.getElementById("display3letter");

function clearAndShow () {
    // Split input box value by comma
    titles = titleInput.value.split(",");

    // Reset display divs
    display2letter.innerHTML = "";
    display3letter.innerHTML = "";

    // Cache length so it's not recalculated on each iteration.
    var len = titles.length;
    var twoletter = [];
    var threeletter = [];

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Check for a-z, A-Z, length 2 or 3
        if (!titles[i].match(/^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/)) {
            throw new Error("Please use only alphabet letters.");
            break;
        }

        // Dump into storage arrays.
        if(titles[i].length == 2) {
                twoletter.push(titles[i]);
        }
        else {
            threeletter.push(titles[i]);
        }
    }

    display2letter.innerHTML += "Titles, 2 letters: " + twoletter.join(", ") + "<br/>";
    display3letter.innerHTML += "Titles, 3 letters: " + threeletter.join(", ") + "<br/>";
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (temporarily; only on the client side) store user input in javascript variables. Create a container (div) and use Javascript HTML DOM API to update it with the required value.

Here is the JavaScript DOM reference guide from w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try looking into JQuery for an easy way to do this..  What you are doing is simple enough where you probably don't need JQuery but would make it a lot simpler for learning.

Here is a quick jsFiddle give a short example of getting values from a text box and appending them to another element.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tvcnx/

HTML:

```
<label>Enter you name:</label><input id="name" type ="text"/><br/>
<h1 id="message"></h1>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#name').change(function(){
        $('#message').html('Hello ' + $('#name').val());
    });
});
```

And here is the documentation on getting values easily with jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Again jQuery is not required but since you appear new it might be easier.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a complete example taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) which shows how to accomplish what you want. If you want to save the user input to show it to the user later, take a look at a [tutorial about cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to demonstrate the prompt box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x;

var person=prompt("Please enter your name","Harry Potter");

if (person!=null)
  {
  x="Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/ Be wary.