# How can i add a bulleted list to my java script code. Also how do i center the the user input like <center> but in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to know how i can make it so when people input something it goes in a bulleted list, in the middle of the screen. Like    but in javascript?
I got my code from: [How to display input back to the user on an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443834/how-to-display-input-back-to-the-user-on-an-html-page)

```
 <html><head></head><body>

<input id="title" type="text" maxlength="276"  onkeyup="Allow()" >
<input type="submit" value="Save/Show" onclick="insert()" />
<div id="display"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var titles  = [];
var titleInput  = document.getElementById("title");
var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");

function Allow(){
    if (!user.title.value.match(/[a-zA-Z1-9]$/) && user.title.value !="") {
        user.title.value="";
        alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
    }
}

function insert () {
    titles.push(titleInput.value);
    clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow () {
    titleInput.value = "";
    messageBox.innerHTML = "";
 messageBox.innerHTML += "To Do: " + titles.join(",   ") + "<br/>";
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

jsbin example: https://jsbin.com/xahidolibu/edit?html,output

Comment: What have *you* tried apart from copying a whole bunch of code from another question? Did you notice that question was closed because it didn't match [this checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code to:

- create a list instead of comma deliminated string on `clearAndShow()`
- added css to center align the list

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/lamebopidu/1/edit?html,css,output